# Not able to insert HTML

Tags: jquery

Does anyone see why the $('' line breaks the jQuery below? There's a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZBRP/2/.   If you comment out the $('div') line the code at least compiles and hits the debugger line when you right-click #box.

```
$(function() {

    $('#box').contextmenu(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var document_offset;
        debugger;
        doc_offset = $(this).offset();
        $('<div>').css({width:150px, height:150px});
     });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing `$('<div>')` rather than `$('div')`? Don't know if that's your issue.

Comment: Use firebug or developer tools to check issues in console. It is throwing an error: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
 

$('<div>').css({width:150px, height:150px});

Comment: @MitulP91 ~ passing in an HTML string to the jQuery function creates that HTML element for you. I mean, yeah it's valid syntax, so it won't throw any errors. There isn't much happening with the new `<div>` though, so there's that...

Comment: Yes, I saw the Syntax error and same thing happens without the < >.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('<div>').css({width:"150px", height:"150px"});
```

unquoted strings.

Comment: While the answer is correct, it might be interesting to note that the OP's code won't really do anything with the newly created `<div>` instance.

Comment: Alternatively, you can leave the values unquoted (as long as you deal with integers).  Therefore, `$('<div>').css({width:150, height:150});` would also be valid (and the values are assumed to be px values).

Comment: Yes!  That's it!  The px makes it a string so it has to be quoted. 'Sorry for missing that.   And yes, I realize the posted code won't do anything.  There's a lot more below that that I removed it to get the minimum I could post here that failed.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you be using this:

```
$('div').css({width:"150px", height:"150px"});
```

instead of:

```
$('<div>').css({width:150px, height:150px});
```

Or try to qoute the styles. However, I have not tried using the angle brackets but still try it.

Comment: This is as invalid as the OP's code, because the values in the object need to be either a valid string (quoted) or integers (no px at the end)

Comment: I mentioned it at the end, to use Qoutes.